# Does Apple LLVM 5.0 support the GCC_ENABLE_OBJC_GC flag?

Tags: xcode, macos, garbage-collection, llvm

I'm using Xcode 5, and thus only have the Apple LLVM 5.0 compiler option. Does it respect the GCC_ENABLE_OBJC_GC flag? I set it to supported on every target in my prefpane project, but Console keeps reporting "GC: forcing GC OFF because OBJC_DISABLE_GC is set". Any ideas?

Comment: Note: Apple deprecated garbage collection in Mountain Lion in favor of ARC, and garbage collection will be removed at a future time. So if you want your app to continue to work, you should transition your code to ARC. According to Apple: "Garbage collection is deprecated in OS X Mountain Lion v10.8, and will be removed in a future version of OS X. Automatic Reference Counting is the recommended replacement technology. To aid in migrating existing applications, the ARC migration tool in Xcode 4.3 and later supports migration of garbage collected OS X applications to ARC."

Comment: Another note: According to the Xcode release notes, Xcode 5 is the last version that will support even building a project that contains garbage collection, so it's even more reason to transition away from it. And the Mac App Store probably won't even accept apps built using garbage collection (or soon won't) because the app store policies apparently say that you're not supposed to use deprecated technologies.